# Short Date to Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, type-conversion

Good Day

I am trying to convert a short date i.e 780506 to a date i.e 1978/05/06 , I have tried CASTING the date `CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 78) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 05) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 06)
 AS DATETIME)` but this is not working. I tried Converting the date:`CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), 780506), 12)` and also not working. Is there am easy way to do this? The reason I need this is that the first 6 digits of out countries ID number = Date of Birth, I am just trying to convert it into a workable date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `date` type:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(10) = '780506'
SELECT convert(DATE, @s)
```

For the column:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, ColumnName) FROM TableName
```

Comment: Hi This works perfect for a single value, but I need to convert a whole column called: ID_DATE. How would I declare that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CAST` or `CONVERT`. Like this:

```
DECLARE @shortdate VARCHAR(10) = '780506'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @shortdate)
SELECT CAST(@shortdate AS DATE)
```

Result:

```
1978-05-06
```